# Combobox binding to array fails

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, arraylist

I'm so sorry to ask about this, but I'm really new in WPF and I searched for hours trying to find out what's the matter on this problem.

Given following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Data> _Buffer = new List<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            _Buffer.Add(new Data(i, i.ToString()));
        }

        //Also tried:
        //comboBox1.DataContext = _Buffer.ToArray();
        comboBox1.ItemsSource = _Buffer.ToArray();
        comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Val";
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "ValName";
        comboBox1.UpdateLayout();
        comboBox1.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBox1_SelectionChanged);
    }

    void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((Data)e.AddedItems[0]).ValName);
    }

    struct Data
    {
        public Data(int Val, string ValName)
        {
            this.Val = Val;
            this.ValName = ValName;
        }
        public readonly int Val;
        public readonly string ValName;
    }
}
```

I guess it suppose to be incredibly easy to bind a simple array to a combo, and actually it is, except for a little problem, it does not show anything in the combo's list.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,82,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

How is the right way to do this?

Comment: Hi, Your are doing two bindings to the ComboBox, this may be affecting, according to your case: erase the binding made in XAML

Comment: Hello Dante, I rid the ItemsSource="{Binding}" but it keeps doing same =( ... actually, the combo "has" the Data objects, but it does not show the associated text

Comment: Have you tried making Val and ValName a property? `public int Val { get; private set; }`

Comment: OMG! that's right!!! I changed by properties and now it is being shown okay...but, why??!!! it suppose to be intended like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` are paths for the item binding you have to make `Val` and `ValName` a property:

```
public int Val { get; private set; }
public string ValName { get; private set; }
```